# I'm unable to insert data into elasticserach through k8's external service using Postman

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, sbt, akka-http

I created a simple scala application, that uses akkaHttp to add user data into Elasticsearch, akkaHttp is running on "0.0.0.0" and has port "8083".

```
Http().newServerAt("0.0.0.0", 8083).bind(route)
```

While for Elasticserach I have create an " `application.conf` " file where i have put the " `elasticserch service` " and "port"

Here is the application.conf content

```
svc
  {
    serviceName = "elastic-service"
    portNumber = 9200
  }
```

In application

```
val applicationConf = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
val host = applicationConf.getString("svc.serviceName")
val port = applicationConf.getInt("svc.portNumber")
val http = new HttpHost(host, port)
val esClient: RestClient = RestClient.builder(http).build();
```

After that I created " `deployments` " and " `services` " for `application` and `elasticsearch` which are given below:

deployment.yaml for application

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: akka-deployment

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: akka-label
  template:
    metadata:
      name: akka-pod
      labels:
        app: akka-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: akka-container
          image: elasticdeployment:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8083
```

service.yaml for application (external service)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: akka-service

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: akka-label
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8083
```

deployment.yaml for elasticsearch

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elastic-deployment

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elastic-label
  template:
    metadata:
      name: elastic-pod
      labels:
        app: elastic-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: elastic-container
          image: elasticsearch:8.4.3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
```

service.yaml for elasticsearch (internal service)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elastic-service

spec:
  selector:
    app: elastic-label
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
```

Without using k8's deployment my application is working fine, i.e I'm able to add user data into ES and get the data from ES as well. But by adding k8's deployment, and try to add the data through loadbalancer using Postman also got error

> An error occurred: Connection refused

Where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to add `targetPort` to your service definition so it will looks like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elastic-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: elastic-label
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8083
```

By default `service` will assume that `port` that is allocated for `LB` is the same as application port.
In your case `LB` port is `8080` and application port is `8083` so you need to explicitly define it.

Comment: I have added the targetPort: 8083 as well by mistakenly i didn't copy that. , stilll it's not working

Comment: Could you run `kubectl get svc elastic-service -o yaml` and see what is the value for `protocol`? I am not sure (and don't have option to test it now) what is default protocol.

Comment: I have update my question, kindly review it.

Comment: From `k8s` perspective all looks fine. `label` and `selector` are ok to me.
I assume that `An error occurred: Connection refused` is produced by `postman` so could you provide some logs from actual `pod` that is running you application? I am wonder if there is still some problem on network level (there will be nothing in `pod` log) or it is application itself.

Comment: I have checked, logs as well, they print nothing, means they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

There were tow problems with my project.

1. OOMKill (Out Of Memory Kill) this is because of limited resources, so I increase My minikube resources by using

   minikube start --cpus=4 --memory=7168
2. Another issue was security that's was true by default in Elasticsearch.
   so I disable it using ConfigMap, here is the solution.

ConfigMap.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-configmap
data:
  es.discovery.type: single-node
  es.xpack.security.enabled: "false"
  es.xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: "false"
  es.xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: "false"
```

deployment.yaml for elasticsearch

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elastic-deployment

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elastic-label
  template:
    metadata:
      name: elastic-pod
      labels:
        app: elastic-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: elastic-container
          image: elasticsearch:8.4.3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
          env:
            - name: discovery.type
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.discovery.type
            - name: xpack.security.enabled
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.xpack.security.enabled
            - name: xpack.security.enrollment.enabled
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.xpack.security.enrollment.enabled
            - name: xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled
```

service.yaml for elasticsearch (internal service)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elastic-service

spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: elastic-label
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
```